# Passing invisible arguments on Flask

Tags: python, flask

today I had a problem, I tried to pass an argument without make it visible, but if I use: `return redirect(url_for('results.get_chapters', title=button))` the variable "button" is visible on the link for example:

https://localhost:5000/variabletext

Anyone knows a solution without using session method from Flask (it can create problems on my code)?

Answer (score 1):

redirect is a get call, so it uses the url. use a post-call instead.